# C++ typedef static function pointer: undefined symbol

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

```
//class.h
 typedef double (*ffunct)(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
 class Class {
    public:
        static ffunct myfunct;
        static void setFunct();
        static double doSomething(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
        static void call();
 }

 //class.cpp
 void Class::setFunct(){
     Class::myfunct=Class::doSomething;
 }
 double Class::doSomething(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
     cout << "Hello World" << endl;
 }
 void Class::call() {
     Class::myfunct(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);
 }
 //main.cpp
 …
 Class::setFunct();
 Class::call();
 …
```

Running the programm results in `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "Class::myfunct", referenced from Class::setFunct, Class::call…`

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cpp file you need one more line:

```
ffunct Class::myfunct = NULL;
```

The class declaration said that the variable would exist *somewhere* but you never gave it a definition. Since it's not part of each object it has to be defined separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype of `doSomething` has a return type of `double`, but your implementation thereof has a return type of *`void`*.

```
static double doSomething(...)
...
void Class::doSomething(...)
```

Fixing this won't clear all the errors however. You still have a few more as the other answers mention.

Answer (score 1):

`static ffunct myfunct;` is a declaration

You need a definition of it also in the cpp file

`ffunct Class::myfunct;`

Answer (score 0):

add one line on the top of your .cpp file:

```
ffunct Class::myfunct=NULL;
```